# Toolbar not showing in Eclipse Neon in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using Eclipse Neon IDE (for Java EE developers) in Ubuntu 17.04.
I tried other versions of eclipse also, but I am not able to see tool bar in the eclipse.
Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance 
[image: screen-shot for the same..]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be [Eclipse bug 516408](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516408). Maybe it is already fixed in Eclipse Oxygen. If not, please add a comment in the Eclipse bug and try following workaround:

> [Workaround: Use Ubuntu 16.04 (gtk-3.18.9), or set SWT_GTK3=0](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516408#c2)

Comment: I tried Eclipse Oxygen too, but the issue is present in this version too.

Comment: Too bad. Did you also try to start Eclipse from a terminal: `export SWT_GTK3=0` and then run `eclipse`?

Comment: As of now, I was just starting the eclipse by double clicking the eclipse executable file. But I will try to do the same through terminal as well.